# How to plot a scatter figure in 3d?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot, 3d

I'm stuck with an error in trying to plot points in 3d using scatter.

```
matr_u = [u,u2,u10,u14,u20]
x = [np.zeros(len(u)),2*np.ones(len(u2)),10*np.ones(len(u10)),14*np.ones(len(u14)),20*np.ones(len(u20))]
r = [r1,r2,r10,r14,r20]
```

And I'm trying to plot it as follows:

```
    fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

for i in range(0,5):
    x=x[i]
    for j in range(0,len(x)):
        ax.scatter( x,r[j],matr_u[j])

ax.set_xlabel('x')
ax.set_ylabel('u')
ax.set_zlabel('r')
plt.show()
```

**ValueError: shape mismatch: objects cannot be broadcast to a single shape**

Now, I'd like to have, for each x[i] a plot of u=u(r), then stepping to the next x[i] and so on..

Any help is highly appreciated!
Thanks

Comment: Try replacing `x=x[i]` by `xx=x[i]`. Don't use the same variable for assignment. Use any other variable name than x. I have used xx

Comment: And then use `for j in range(0,len(xx)):`